There is a problem with the windows application. SystemChrome
/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/title.dart(40,5): error G4127D1E8: The getter 'SystemChrome' isn't defined for the class 'Title'. [D:\development\secret_notes\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/view.dart(356,7): error G4127D1E8: The getter 'SystemChrome' isn't defined for the class 'RenderView'. [D:\development\secret_notes\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/view.dart(375,5): error G4127D1E8: The getter 'SystemChrome' isn't defined for the class 'RenderView'. [D:\development\secret_notes\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(254,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'D:\development\secret_notes\build\windows\x64\CMakeFiles\73f54689014748040d68dab94af167c3\flutter_windows.dll.rule;D:\development\secret_notes\build\windows\x64\CMakeFiles\4c45d7c9b961ed0f657924615ad28d1e\flutter_assemble.rule;D:\development\secret_notes\windows\flutter\CMakeLists.txt' exited with code 1. [D:\development\secret_notes\build\windows\x64\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Error: Build process failed.
i re-install Desktop development with C++,flutter clean & flutter pub get, dart fix, dart cache repair, How can we solve this?

Do you have installed Visual Studio?

of course......

I forgot to write.   SystemUiOverlayStyleSystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
]);
after running this code this error appeared in every project. Don't worry, after removing the code, I did the operations I mentioned above.

I installed sdk again and it's fixed.
